# MySQL group by maximum value in a row

Tags: mysql

> I need a SQL query which will give give you Student name subject wise,
>   whose marks is highest

**Table**

```
ID    StudentName    Subject    Marks
1     A              English    50
2     B              English    40 
3     C              English    60
4     D              Science    10
5     E              Science    30
6     F              Science    20
```

**desired result**

```
C       English        
E       Science
```

Comment: google sql group by maximum

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM somewhere x JOIN (SELECT subject, MAX(marks) max_marks FROM datable GROUP BY subject) y ON something and something

Comment: What do you want to happen if two students share the highest mark?

Comment: Why do you think we want to do your work for you? What have you tried, and what went wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do Self Join.
Something like this.
This will print students having highest marks.

```
SELECT table_name.StudentName,table_name.Subject
FROM
table_name INNER JOIN 
(SELECT `Subject`,MAX(`Marks`) AS Marks FROM table_name GROUP by `Subject`) T
ON  table_name.Marks=T.Marks AND table_name.`Subject` = T.`Subject`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not how GROUP BY works, an arbitrary id will be selected from each subject group, not the id corresponding to the MAX.

Comment: Still no, you'll need the subject in the inner query and join on that too

Comment: Still wrong I'm afraid, you aren't selecting the subject in the inner query

Comment: Bingo, although maybe you could point out that this could list more than one student for each subject in the case that the top mark wasn't unique.

Comment: This query return the complete row and I need only Subject and student Name.

Comment: "SELECT student_name, subject, MAX(marks) FROM student GROUP BY subject"  

Can you please explain why above query give me wrong result always...it gives me........
A      English   60,    
D      Maths    30

Comment: @GaganUpadhyay Because you are not including the non-aggregate column `student_name` in the `GROUP BY` statement, so an arbitrary value of `student_name` is chosen from the group.. there is nothing linking it to the `MAX(marks)` as each column value is selected independently.

Comment: Understood ....Thanks Arth.....I knew this rule but I am not able to recall it....Thanks you so much